# Is there a legal professional who can be hired to assist with insurance for patients with complicated medical needs?

Tags: united-states, medical, health-insurance, indiana

Is there a specific category of legal professional that could be hired specifically to assist with the filing of the paperwork and management of insurance claims on behalf of an individual?

I am not seeking advice for a specific case, rather I am trying to determine what kind of specialized legal professional should be contacted for a consultation. I think such a professional would need a legal background since this is fundamentally a contract issue with the insurance company.